# Expectation of the log shifted-gamma

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, gamma-distribution

If $X \sim \Gamma(a, \beta)$ and $c$ some constant then $Y=X+c$ follows a shifted Gamma distribution with pdf
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{\beta^a}{\Gamma(a)}(y-c)^{a-1}e^{-(y-c)\beta}$$

$y\in[c, +\infty)$. What is the expectation of $ Z = \log Y $ please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the solution is not 'easy'.

Let $X \sim \text{Gamma}(a,b)$ with pdf $f(x)$, where $b = \frac{1}{\beta}$, and assume $c>0$:

[image]

Then, the desired expectation $\mathbb{E}[\log(X+c)]$ is:

[image]

... using here the *Expect* function from the *mathStatica* add-on to *Mathematica*, and where links are provided to the definitions of the [*HypergeometricPFQ*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html) and [*PolyGamma*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyGamma.html) functions.

Numerical checking via Monte Carlo suggests the solution appears correct (avoid discontinuity at integer valued *a*).

Comment: The numerical checking is wise, because results have have explicitly nonzero imaginary parts are not trustworthy!  There must be a simplification that makes the result an obviously real number.

Comment: Yes there should be a simpler form, I wish I could figure it out....